# Configuration Class property in LocalSessionFactoryBean migration from Hibernate 3 to 4.3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've come across a little problem concerning the utilization of Configuration classes in bean injection when migrating to Hibernate 4.3.

The configuration class I inject overrides certain methods from the org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration Class like validateSchema()

In Hibernate 3, I have this in my configuration file and it works because the get/set methods for configurationClass exists :

```
<bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="$[DATA_SOURCE]" />
    </property>

    <property name="entityInterceptor">
        <ref bean="entityInterceptor"/>
    </property>

    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>com.hibernate.cfg.CustomSchemaValidationConfiguration</value>    
    </property>
```

Meanwhile, in Hibernate 4.3, I get this error because the setConfigurationClass() method doesn't exist anymore.

```
Invalid property 'configurationClass' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean]: Bean property 'configurationClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Thing is that I still want/need to use que configuration class. 
I've seen many examples in code but I want to stay with the spring injection way. Is it posible ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: There is no more configuration class and the support that is still there is going away. There is a whole new configuration model, you would have to adapt your solution to that instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum do you have something that I can lookup? Either By beans or    code about the new Model ?